# How do I remove a row based on a specific vector within a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have an online survey dataset in which there are multiple complete attempts by participants and I need to selectively remove several of the cases by row number.  The data is stored as a data.frame. I realize I could do this manually, but I want to keep this as a script so that I can use it later if need be or someone can duplicate what I've done quickly and efficiently.

What I have tried: I have searched in multiple locations, but my question seems too simple.  I have looked at removing rows based on incomplete cases ('complete.cases' and 'na.omit'), but this is not specifically want I want as I am trying to remove a row based on a specific vector within the data.frame

The data:

```
user_id var1 var2 var3
1         NA   13  bob
3       time   37 fred
4     second   NA lisa
5     second   28 lisa
```

So, in the above data.frame I have multiple attempts by user lisa.  I want to keep her last attempt because it is more complete (no NA in `var2`), but I need to remove the row based on `user_id` rather than `var3`.

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove all cases except one for a particular user (var3), and you want to remove those that have missing data first?

Comment: So 'completeness' is the number of non-NAs in var1 and var2? And you want to keep the most complete row for each of the values in var3? So even though bob was as incomplete as lisa's first go, his entry stays because he never did any better? Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove row 4 from the data above which is user_id 4. Yes, to both of you actually.  I'm not concerned with a row that has a few NAs, but only keeping the most complete attempt by respondents who attempted the survey multiple times.

Comment: What if Lisa had two complete records? What if Bob had two records (i.e. rows) with one NA in each? In both cases, do you want to keep both records?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien at that point I would need to apply another filter and choose the most recent attempt using date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
> data
  var1 var2 var3  user
1    1   NA    2   bob
2   34    3    1   bob
3   NA   NA    2   bob
4    1    2    3  lisa
5    1   NA    2  lisa
6    3    4    5   joe
7    6   NA    4 simon
```

first compute the completeness score by summing the number of non-NA values in var1 to var3:

```
> data$score = apply(data[,c("var1","var2","var3")],1,function(x){sum(!is.na(x))})
> data
  var1 var2 var3  user score
1    1   NA    2   bob     2
2   34    3    1   bob     3
3   NA   NA    2   bob     1
4    1    2    3  lisa     3
5    1   NA    2  lisa     2
6    3    4    5   joe     3
7    6   NA    4 simon     2
```

Then find the row with max(score) in each group. There's probably an easier way to do this:

```
> pick = unlist(tapply(1:7,data$user,
      function(x){x[data[x,"score"]==max(data[x,"score"])]}))
> pick
  bob   joe  lisa simon 
    2     6     4     7 
> data[pick,]
  var1 var2 var3  user score
2   34    3    1   bob     3
6    3    4    5   joe     3
4    1    2    3  lisa     3
7    6   NA    4 simon     2
```

If someone has two rows with the same score they'll appear twice:

```
> data[2,'var2']=NA
> data$score = apply(data[,c("var1","var2","var3")],1,function(x){sum(!is.na(x))})
```

Now if I recompute *pick* I get bob twice:

```
> pick = unlist(tapply(1:7,data$user,
    function(x){x[data[x,"score"]==max(data[x,"score"])]}))
> pick
 bob1  bob2   joe  lisa simon 
    1     2     6     4     7
```

Which can be fixed by just returning the first match in the pick calculation:

```
> pick = unlist(tapply(1:7,data$user,
  function(x){x[data[x,"score"]==max(data[x,"score"])][1]}))
> pick
  bob   joe  lisa simon 
    1     6     4     7
```

You didn't say what you wanted doing with duplicates...

Someone will probably have a one-liner posted in a tic...

Comment: This is helpful thanks.  It's leading me in the direction.  I think another option would be to filter it by user and date/time, which I should have included in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
setwd("~/Stack Overflow")
MultipleSurveys <- read.table("~/Stack Overflow/ ...
MultipleSurveys.txt", header=T, quote="\"")
SurvDat <- MultipleSurveys[,-ncol(MultipleSurveys)][,-1]
NbNA <- rowSums(is.na(SurvDat)); names(NbNA) <- "NbNA"
AMS <- cbind(MultipleSurveys,NbNA)
minNA <- function(DT){
  NbSurv <- nrow(DT)
  if (NbSurv==1) return(DT)
  else{
    OldRow <- DT[1,]
    for (r in 2:NbSurv){
      NewRow <- DT[r,]
      if (NewRow$NbNA<=OldRow$NbNA) OldRow <- NewRow
    }
    return(OldRow)
  }
}
(SingleSurveys <- by(AMS,AMS$user,minNA))
```